# Retrofit Doesn't Send Request to Server and stops. Once the phone is rebooted it works properly

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I am working in an app where i am using retrofit for api call, the issue is that in some devices it works properly. but sometimes it doesn't send request, it stops send request. And when phone is rebooted it starts working again. Why is that so, Can you please Help me.

Comment: can you give more details? how you create service call, what are the logs etc.?

Comment: Try this by putting this inside application in Manifest  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: @TanamyRanjan i have already included it.

Comment: @ycannot the app is working fine in many devices but, in some device it stops send request at that time either we have to reinstall app or restart the phone then it again start working properly.